# From Java World to SharePoint

Tags: development

I am newbie in Microsoft world. In fact I am planning to move in SharePoint development. I am just wondering, to ask some questions before moving to this world. I have knowledge in Servlet, and Portlet development using Java. I have to develop similar solutions in future: for example consuming web services, presenting data, manipulating databases and many other common web component developments with proper user role management.

I know all these are possible in SharePoint as well, But my question is:

**As I don't have a background in ASP.NET, is it going to be hard to develop applications such as those in SharePoint? Or I can start developing such applications for SharePoint sites without having any prior knowledge to these Microsoft technologies?**

Although I have little knowledge in C# style only :)

Thank you for your kind suggestions in advance!

BR

Arko

P.S.: Any kind of useful websites and tutorial suggestions are also welcomed in this thread! Tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are working mostly with SP 2013 your life will be much easier. SharePoint has a very robust set of web services as well as a new workflow model that is declarative (not code based) that is designed so that the business logic is moved into external web services. So you could use Java, PHP, Ruby, etc to actually write the parts of your applications that handle the heavy lifting.

You will still need to know how to use Visual Studio but for the most part SharePoint 2013 has a very good story for web developers familiar with standard web technologies like JavaScript and HTML. This wasn't always true in older versions.

That being said, there will be times when you will have to use C# and ASP.net to get certain things done. But you will still be able to use a lot of your existing knowledge as well.

For training, take a look at the [MS Virtual Academy](http://microsoftvirtualacademy.com) site and [PluralSight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses) (paid, I am not affiliated but I have been a subscriber for 3 years now). I believe [they currently have 100 courses on SharePoint](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses#sharepoint). [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/) is another great place to find training.

Comment: Hello Robert, 
Thank you very much for your answer. I just want to know one additional information. Is it also possible to consume web services from SAP and other applications without code ? 
I am planning to use SP 2013 to communicate with SAP and save information in Database and then visualize them in charts. Some users will also have right to edit information saved in database. 
I know how to do this all things in Java portlet application like Liferay. But I am planning to learn SharePoint 2013 as many people argued that It is a cool  and quick approach.

Comment: I would ask that as another question. The only thing I am familiar with about SAP integration is that SAP has a component called Duet that's integrated with SharePoint. http://www.sap.com/pc/tech/collaboration-content-management/software/duet-enterprise/index.html